Is the L1-norm of the following matrix equal or greater than 1/3？
Suppose $\mathbf{A}$ is an $n×n$ symmetric positive definite matrix with nonpositive off-diagonal elements, and there is $$\mathrm{min[{eig(\mathbf{A})}]} = 1$$
, i.e., the smallest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$ is equal to 1.

The question is: How to prove
$$||(\mathbf{A}+2\mathbf{I}){^-}{^1}||{_1} \geq \frac{1}{3}$$
, where $||·||{_1}$ is the greatest sum of absolute values of each column of a matrix; $\mathbf{I}$ is the unit matrix.
(Sorry for the frequent change. There were mistakes in the previous statement.)
(Thanks for a rural reader's comment)

How about ‘Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix with nonpositive off-diagonal elements, …’?

Let $v$ be an eigenvector corresponding to the unit eigenvalue of $A$. Normalise it so that $\|v\|_1=1$. Then
$$
\|(A+2I)^{-1}\|_1
=\max_{\|u\|_1=1}\|(A+2I)^{-1}u\|_1
\ge\|(A+2I)^{-1}v\|_1
=\left\|\frac13v\right\|_1
=\frac13.
$$
The assumptions that $A$ is positive definite, $A$ has non-positive off-diagonal entries and $1$ is the minimum eigenvalue of $A$ are useless. All we need are the invertibility of $A+2I$ and that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.
